# Prove that S is disconnected if and only if there is a nonempty subset A of S such that A does not equal S and A is both open and closed.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that a metric space S is disconnected if and only if there is a nonempty subset A of S such that A does not equal S and A is both open and closed.

We know the definition of disconnected is: A set E ⊂ S is said to be disconnected if and only if there are disjoint, nonempty subsets A and B of E that are open in E and such that E = A∪B. A set in S is said to be connected if and only if it is not disconnected.

How do I go about showing a set is open and closed and relating that to the set being disconnected? Also, what should I assume for the proof of (if) and (only if)?

Comment: Hint: if $A$ is both open and closed then: $A$ is open, and $ B = A^{c}$ is also open (since $A$ is closed). Now you can relate to your definition...

Answer (score 2):

A $space$ $S$ is disconnected

iff there exists non-empty open disjoint $A, B$ with $B=S$ \ $A$

iff there exists  non-empty open $A\ne S$ with $S$ \ $A$ open

iff there exists a non-empty open $A\ne S$ with  $S$ \ $(S$ \ $A)$  closed

iff there exists non-empty open $A \ne S$ with $A$ closed.

This applies to all topological spaces.

Comment: Is it always true that $A,B$ must be disjoint?

Comment: @IntegrateThis.  The statement that $S$ is disconnected iff $S$ has two disjoint non-empty open sets $A, B$ with $A\cup B=S$ (or equivalently that $B=S\backslash A$) is the most commonly-used definition of "disconnected"